# What does ''touch more arch'' mean here?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> I'd never been one for this type of sloganeering—I liked my mottoes to be a touch more arch...

What does 'a touch more arch' mean here?

I think I know both what 'touch' and 'arch' mean, but I just can't understand what 'touch more arch' means here. Any idea?

Comment: 'A touch' here means 'a small amount'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you think you know what *arch* means, but just to be sure: it's not the noun meaning the round or pointy feature of buildings. It's an adjective meaning 'playful, mischievous or cunning' (we might refer to someone's 'arch sense of humour'). Mottos and slogans are very short and memorable phrases associated with schools, cities, businesses or political parties or candidates, but they don't really tell us much. McDonald's slogan 'I'm loving it' doesn't really tell us much about the food or the company.

This person doesn't like the short, straightforwardness of (whatever they are talking about). They like the discussion to be more playful or cunning, and possibly longer longer than most mottoes or slogans.

Answer (score 1):

*touch* has many (related, but still different) meanings. You can refer to [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/touch#dictionary-entry-2), definition 7b:

> 7: something slight of its kind: such as
>    b : a small quantity or indication : hint
>     // a *touch* of spring in the air

In this case, you can also replace it with the word 'bit'.